# I can't start dbus services on MacOS M1

Tags: service, homebrew, apple-m1, dbus

Hi I have a problem to start dbus services. 
% brew services
Name        Status User File 
dbus        none
mailcatcher none
php         none
pulseaudio  none
unbound     none
% brew services start dbus 
Error: Formula `dbus` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file 
Anyone knows how to solve it?
I expected: 
% brew services start dbus 
Successfully started `dbus`

Comment: This is a question better asked on the PowerUser site.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved it, I just needed to input brew services start "d-bus" instead of "dbus". I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: as of 2023-04-07, `d-bus` is deprecated in favor of `dbus`, so this is at least out of date.

Comment: Maybe out of date but after hours of struggles this answer finally made things work for me ! Thanks